# How to show 3D building with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, 3d-map

How can I use Leaflet and OpenStreetMap to display 3D buildings for free? I find same scripts but needs API key or access token. Who already has a script to show 3D map Leaflet using open source?

---

i tried with osmBuilding but the codes which i find doesn't works good, have scripte .hmtl work well?

Comment: You can try out https://www.wrld3d.com/#INTRO or https://cesium.com/ for 3d mapping application. If you're specific to leaflet, you can also try out https://osmbuildings.org/ which is a leaflet plugin.